The upper bound of Lipschitz function with cell problem
Let us consider the Hamiltonian $H = H(y,p): \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$,which is continuous and satisfies below.
(H1) For each $p\in\mathbb{R}^n, y\mapsto H(y,p)$ is $\mathbb{Z}^n-periodic.$
(H2) For y $\in\mathbb{T}^n$, $\lim_{|p|\to \infty} H(y,p) = +\infty$.
(H3)For each y $\in\mathbb{T}^n$, $p\mapsto H(y,p)$ is convex.
It was known that there exists a unique constant $\overline{H}(p)\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the following cell problem has a Lipschitz continuous viscosity solution
$H(y, p + Dv) = \overline{H}(p)$ in $\mathbb{T}^n$.(1.1)
In this paper, they assume further that H grows quadratically, that is,
$|p|^2/2$ - C $\le$ H(y,p) $\le$ $|p|^2/2$ + C for all (y,p)$\in$ $\mathbb{T}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$,
for some C >1. Then, we also have that
$|p|^2/2$ - C $\le$ $\overline{H}(p)$ $\le$ $|p|^2/2$ + C for all p$\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n$.
They use two inequalities above to get that, for each Lipschitz function $v_{p}$ solving(1.1), $||Dv_{p}||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^n)}$ $\leq$ 2(|p| + C).
But I cannot get this inequality. Can you help me?

Did you try the formal argument first, assuming $v$ is a classical solution? Here, you'd have
$$|p|^2/2 + p\cdot Dv + |Dv|^2/2 - C =|p + Dv|^2/2 - C \leq H(y,p+Dv) = \overline{H(p)} \leq |p|^2/2 + C.$$
Therefore
$$|Dv|^2/2 \leq 2C - p\cdot Dv \leq 2C + |p||Dv|,$$
which is equivalent to
$$(|Dv| - |p|)^2\leq 4C + |p|^2.$$
Taking square roots on both sides we have
$$|Dv| - |p| \leq \sqrt{4C + |p|^2} \leq 2\sqrt{C} + |p|,$$
and so
$$|Dv| \leq 2(\sqrt{C} + |p|).$$
I assume the value of $C$ can change in their paper.
Now, you have to do this argument in the viscosity sense. Take a smooth test function $\phi$ such that $v-\phi$ has a local max at $x$, and then run the argument above with $D \phi(x)$ in place of $Dv$...

Thanks a lot! This is helpful!
